# Using filters with SQL union

Tags: sql-server, union

I have this SQL Server query. Executing this query will be give list of claimnumbers and UW_Peril.

SQL Server:

```
select 
    ClaimNum, UW_Peril  
from 
    tableA

union

select  
    ClaimNum, UW_Peril 
from 
    (select 
         claimNum, 'Litigation' as UW_Peril 
     from 
         tableB
     where 
         Litigation = 1 and OrderofSuitReceived = 1) lt
```

I have 2 cases:

1. if there is only one row per claim number then leave it as it is.
2. But if there is more than row per claim number, then select the row where UW_Peril = 'Litigation'

**Example:**

```
ClaimNum    UW_Peril
--------------------------
2053057     Litigation
2053057     Theft
2053125     Litigation
2052452     Subro
```

The expected output

**Example:**

```
ClaimNum    UW_Peril
--------------------------
2053057     Litigation
2053125     Litigation
2052452     Subro
```

How would I modify this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your example output is already the same as your expected output...

Comment: You said if there is is more than 1 row per claim number then select the row where there is `Lititgation` so how would the expected output have more than 1 row per ClaimNum?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` and `not exists` with `union all` :

```
select ClaimNum, UW_Peril
from tableB b
where exists (select 1 
              from tableB b1 
              where b1.ClaimNum = b.ClaimNum and b1.UW_Peril = b.UW_Peril)
union all
select ClaimNum, UW_Peril
from tableB b
where not exists (select 1 
                  from tableB b1 
                  where b1.ClaimNum = b.ClaimNum and b1.UW_Peril = b.UW_Peril) and
      b.UW_Peril = 'Lititgation';
```

Comment: I want the table A to be union'ed with table B, and not like self-union of table B